# PhD application to Austrian University

Tags: application, university

I have a master's degree and I would like to study for a doctorate in Austrian universities and among the questions that are in the application is "Where do you want to carry out your project ? (library, archive, institute)".

How can I answer this question?

Comment: What field are you studying?

Comment: Which university? Which field? Afaik every university here has some kind of students' representative council for PhD students, you should talk to them.

Comment: You should answer the question accurately.

Comment: in filed pharmacology and toxicology and i have proposal in (antibiotic Resistance)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe they just mean: "At which institute (or lab, if applicable) do you plan to implement the project?" And the answer could be "Institute of ... at the University of Vienna" or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm as puzzled about the question as you are. In some fields it might make sense, but doesn't seem to for yours. Perhaps it is just a general question asked of everyone.

I think you need to get guidance on the question from the individual university. Pharmacology research would seem to be most likely carried out in an institute, but perhaps they have a specific meaning.